# Why might GitHub report a public key as invalid?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have generated ssh key.
The result was:

```
Your identification has been saved in /home/rajani/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/rajani/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

The key is in hexa decimal format, but while adding it to GitHub, I am getting error like this:

```
Key is invalid. 
It must begin with 'ssh-rsa' or 'ssh-dss'. 
Check that you're copying the public half of the key .
```

How I should properly add an ssh key to GitHub?

Comment: You can improve your questions by formatting the exact error message as a quote.

Comment: @CodeGnome error message formatted, and +1 to your answer.

Comment: After you generate your ssh key, execute this on terminal: pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub this command will copy the ket to your clipboard. Then, paste it on "Key" field.

Answer (score 7):

#### The Problems

1. The **ssh-keygen** utility usually defaults to generating RSA keys, but your implementation may default to ECDSA, which GitHub does not currently support.
2. If you are truly generating RSA keys, you may be trying to paste your private key to the server, instead of your public key.

#### Solutions

1. Force RSA key generation by passing the **-t** flag to *ssh-keygen*.
2. Make sure you're copying the key with a **.pub** extension, and that you include the *entire* line. This will include the **ssh-rsa** prefix if you're copying an RSA public key.

#### Related

Of course, `man 1 ssh-keygen` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the "hexa decimal part" and put "ssh-rsa " in the front, that should do the trick.